# SwidtUI iOS - Cannot use instance member x within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
struct LePlay: View {

    var fileName: String
    
    init(fileName: String) {
        self.fileName = fileName
    }
    
    @State var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://blala.com/?n=" + fileName)!)
```

I get

Cannot use instance member 'fileName' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

in the last `fileName` in the code

I've already seen similar questions but none of the solutions there are working for me

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory, did you have a specific question about the error? Why do you need `player` to be a `State` variable?

Comment: I don't know, so far I followed a tutorial

Comment: Which tutorial is it?

Comment: Here you can see if the explanation why I need it to be state: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75158327/swift-swiftui-ios-cannot-convert-value-of-type-bindingavplayer-to-expecte#75158486

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to initialise `player` in your `init`, as follows:

```
struct LePlay: View {
    
    var fileName: String
    @State var player: AVPlayer

    init(fileName: String) {
        self.fileName = fileName
        _player = State(wrappedValue: AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://blala.com/?n=" + fileName)!))
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what will happen here, assigning a class to `State`.

You should wrap `player` in an `ObservableObject` class, which you can assign to a `StateObject`

Comment: You should be able to just do it without `_` and `State(wrappedValue:)` as of Xcode 14 at least. 
Though I still don't see why you would ever need an `AVPlayer` to be a `@State`. As Ashley states here, doesn't really make sense to use a `class` as a `State`.