# Swift SwiftUI iOS - Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<AVPlayer?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<AVPlayer>

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
struct LePlay: View {

    var fileName: String
    
    init(fileName: String) {
        self.fileName = fileName
    }
    
    @State var player: AVPlayer? = nil

    @State var isplaying = false
    @State var showcontrols = true
    @State var value : Float = 0
        
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            if(player != nil){
                CustomVideoPlayer(player: self.$player, isplaying: $isplaying)
                    .frame(width: 777, height: 777, alignment: .center)

                
                if(self.showcontrols){
                    Controls(player: self.$player, isplaying: self.$isplaying, pannel: self.$showcontrols, value: self.$value, memeHeight: 777, fileName: fileName)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: fileName)!)
        }
    }
}
```

I get:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<AVPlayer?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<AVPlayer>'
```

Why do I still get this error despite having `if(player != nil){}` ?

Adding ! like `self.$player!` also doesn't solve the problem!

I tried to do just `var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: fileName)!)` right at the beginning but it doesn't work.

Nothing basic just works in this horrendous garbage language, it's disgusting and unintuitive. I'm getting sick and tired of swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing still doesn't change what `player` is.

Take a look at this example...

```
let a: String? = "Hello, world!"

// The type of a is Optional<String> (aka String?)

if a != nil {
  // this code will run because a is not nil
  // but the type of a is still Optional<String>
}
```

To fix your code you can use optional binding...

```
let a: String? = "Hello, world!"

// The type of a is Optional<String> (aka String?)

if let a {
  // this code will run because a is not nil
  // and now the type of a inside this block is String and no longer Optional
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error states that you cannot bind an **optional** type to a **non-optional** `Binding`.

But a `Binding` is not necessary at all, it's even wrong.

1. `AVPlayer` is a subclass of `NSObject`, a reference type. A `@State` property wrapper is for value types. As you certainly are not going to modify the player's reference in memory just pass the reference.
2. As you have implemented `init` initialize the player there.

---

```
struct LePlay: View {

    var fileName: String
    let player: AVPlayer
    
    init(fileName: String) {
        self.fileName = fileName
        player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: fileName)!)
    }
}
```

Delete

```
.onAppear(){
    player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: fileName)!)
}
```

and change

```
CustomVideoPlayer(player: player, isplaying: $isplaying)
```

Replace the `Binding` in `CustomVideoPlayer` and the other class just with

```
let player : AVPlayer
```

Comment: I vote this up since it's a better approach than what I've tried, thanks!

Comment: No offence, your approach is not worse, it's wrong.

Comment: That's true, I'm never offended when someone shows my mistakes but thankful :D

Comment: @EduardUnruh this should be the selected answer. Not mine. This addresses the usage of the AVPlayer itself rather than just the optional value.

Comment: Yes for me personally this is the better answer, but for those who still need exactly what I've asked, your answer would be the correct one? @Fogmeister